# Simple Spark program eats all resources

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have server with running in it Spark master and slave. Spark was built manually with next flags:

```
build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

I'm trying to execute next simple program remotely:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("testApp").setMaster("spark://sparkserver:7077")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        println(sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3)).reduce((a, b) => a + b))
}
```

Spark dependency:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
```

Log on program executing:

```
16/04/12 18:45:46 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

My cluster WebUI:
[image]

Why so simple application uses all availiable resources?

**P.S.** Also I noticed what if I allocate more memory for my app (10 gb e.g.) next logs appear many times:

```
16/04/12 19:23:40 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160412182336-0008/208 is now RUNNING
16/04/12 19:23:40 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20160412182336-0008/208 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
```

I think that reason in connection between master and slave. How I set up master and slave(on the same machine):

```
sbin/start-master.sh
sbin/start-slave.sh spark://sparkserver:7077
```

**P.P.S.** When I'm connecting to spark master with spark-shell all is good:

```
spark-shell --master spark://sparkserver:7077
```

Comment: Perhaps you were trying to run the application while a previous application was running, taking all 8 cores and leaving no available resource for the second application?

Comment: There are no other processes before running my app. All memory are eaten by my app only.

Comment: Trying specificing the number of cores for the app with `spark.executor.cores` flag.

Comment: Specifying core number not helps

Comment: What happens when you kill all tasks and refresh the UI? How many available resources are there?

Comment: There are no resources in using when I kiled my app

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov reduce is action operation, it's not lazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a driver issue. Driver (My scala app) was ran on my local computer. And workers have no access to it. As result all resources were eaten by attempts to reconnect to a driver.

Answer (score 0):

By default, yarn will allocate all "available" ressources if the yarn dynamic ressource allocation is set to true and your job still have queued tasks. You can also look for your yarn configuration, namely the number of executor and the memory allocated to each one and tune in function of your need.

Comment: but I'm not using yarn. I just runed spark master and attached slave to it.

Comment: Even spark standalone cluster will assign all the cores and (total ram - 1gb) of memory to the worker, you should change these params in spark-env.sh please have a look at spark configuration page.

Comment: What is called 'memory in use' is the memory allocated for the executor, i.e. reserved for the executor and that does not imply that your application is consuming all of it.

Answer (score 0):

in file:spark-default.xml ------->setting :spark.cores.max=4